# Write the standard basis vectors as linear combinations of vectors in B?

Tags: linear-algebra

$B = \{b_{1} = (1, 0, 0), b_{2} = (−1, 1, 0), b_{3} = (0, 1, 1) \}$

What exactly is this question asking?
Do I have to us Gaussian elimination and row reduce the matrix for each basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or?

Answer (score 1):

So the standard basis is $\beta = \{ (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) \}$.

You are being asked to take each vector in $\beta$ and write it as a linear combination of vectors in $B$. So as Will Hunting has already demonstrated, $\beta_{1} = b_{1}$, and so the vector $\beta_{1} = (1, 0, 0)_{B}$. This reads, we write the vector $\beta_{1}$ as $(1, 0, 0)$ in terms of basis vectors from $B$.

So $\beta_{2} = (0, 1, 0) = c_{1}b_{1} + c_{2}b_{2} + c_{3}b_{3}$. So if we take $c_{1} = 1, c_{2} = 1$, we get $\beta_{2} = (1, 1, 0)_{B}$. We don't need $b_{3}$ to form the second basis vector.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

The standard basis vectors are $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$.

To express each of the standard basis vectors as linear combinations of the vectors in $B$, $b_1=(1,0,0)$, $b_2=(-1,1,0)$ and $b_3=(0,1,1)$ you want to calculate scalar constants $u_k$, $v_k$ and $w_k$ such that

$$ e_1=u_1b_1+v_1b_2+w_1b_3$$ 
$$ e_2=u_2b_1+v_2b_2+w_2b_3$$
$$ e_3=u_3b_1+v_3b_2+w_3b_3$$

You can represent the above system of equations in matrix form (forming a matrix whose columns are $b_1$, $b_2$ and $b_3$, so that),
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
u_k \\
v_k \\
w_k \end{array} \right)=e_k$$

In terms of how to calculate the scalar constants, you can use a variety of means, and I don't think you have to use Gaussian elimination - using simultaneous equations is just as fine.

For $e_1=(1,0,0)$, note that $b_1=e_1$, which is quite simple, so you obtain $u_1=1$, $v_1=0$ and $w_1=0$. So $e_1=b_1$.

For $e_2=(0,1,0)$, we have $u_2-v_2=0$, $v_2+w_2=1$,$w_2=0$, so that $u_2=1$,$v_2=1$ and $w_2=0$. So $e_2=b_1+b_2$.

For $e_3=(0,0,1)$, we have $u_2-v_2=0$, $v_2+w_2=0$,$w_2=1$, so that $u_2=-1$,$v_2=-1$ and $w_2=1$.So $e_3=-b_1-b_2+b_3$.